# Bring object through interface in order to mock it

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am at a somewhat of a crossroads with the following issue. I have, let's say, the following **class**

```
public class Foo
{
   internal Bar bar { get; }

   internal Foo(Bar bar)
     {
         this.bar = bar;
     }
}
```

and I am trying to a Unit test of it using **XUnit** and **Moq**. The initial test I created was

```
[Theory]
[AutoMockData]
internal void CtorShouldCreateInstance(Bar bar)
{
   var sut = new Foo(bar);

   Assert.NotNull(sut);
}
```

which was a valid unit test, but by passing **Bar** as a parameter it bring all it's dependencies making it as a **concrete** type. The suggestion from my colleague was to bring the **Bar** object through an **Interface** and **Mock** the interface but I am not sure how to do it.

I've thought of making the interface, a method to **CreateBar** with its required parameters, inherit the interface to the **Foo** class, implement the method and then add it to the unit test, but I've wanted to get a clarification or approval as I am not sure this is the correct way.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: `Bar` should be derived from an abstraction like `IBar` That is what should be injected into dependents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do was to pass the **IBar** interface as the parameter instead of the normal **Bar** class, because AutoMockData took care of everything.

So yeah the answer was to make the **Foo** class

```
public class Foo
{
   internal IBar bar { get; }

   internal Foo(Bar bar)
     {
         this.bar = bar;
     }
}
```

and the test becomes

```
[Theory]
[AutoMockData]
internal void CtorShouldCreateInstance(IBar bar)
{
   var sut = new Foo(bar);

   Assert.NotNull(sut);
}
```

Thanks everyone for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to derive Bar from IBar, so then you can Mock it easily with Mocking framework like FakeItEasy, here is an example :

```
public interface IBar
{
    string SayHello();
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        // A complex work to retrieve data from external resource
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly IBar _bar;

    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public string Greeting()
    {
        return _bar.SayHello();
    }
}
```

Now you can mock IBar to return your desired result :

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Bar_ShouldReturn_HiInsteadOfHello()
    {
        IBar fakeBar = A.Fake<IBar>();
        A.CallTo(() => fakeBar.SayHello()).Returns("Hi");

        Foo sut = new Foo(fakeBar);
        Assert.AreEqual(sut.Greeting(), "Hi");
    }
}
```

---

*** Side note:** You can also Mock your method directly without deriving that from an interface by making that virtual, but as a best practice it's better to use interfaces instead :

```
public class Bar
{
    public virtual string SayHello()
    {
        // A complex work to retrieve data from external resource
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly Bar _bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public string Greeting()
    {
        return _bar.SayHello();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class FooTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Bar_ShouldReturn_HiInsteadOfHello()
    {
        Bar fakeBar = A.Fake<Bar>();
        A.CallTo(() => fakeBar.SayHello()).Returns("Hi");

        Foo sut = new Foo(fakeBar);
        Assert.AreEqual(sut.Greeting(), "Hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answered but I am using XUnit so I don't have the methods you exposed in your answer. Although I think I did understand the concept of what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Vlădel Yeah, I used NUnit in this example but there's no big difference between these Test Frameworks, They just use different attribute names. I hope you got the main idea.